# MySQL Performance vs MSSQL Performance

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to compare the basic *insert* performance of **MySql** and **MS SQL Server**. The following MSSQL Query takes 1 second to execute using Business Management studio :

```
declare @i int
set @i=1

while (@i<1000)
begin
    insert into empmast 
        (name) values ( 'Client ' + cast(@i as varchar(10) ))
    set @i = @i + 1
end
go
```

A similar query in WorkBench takes 40 seconds to execute. Here is the Query :

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS xproc_loop_test$$
CREATE PROCEDURE xproc_loop_test()
BEGIN
  DECLARE int_val INT DEFAULT 0;
  test_loop : LOOP
  IF (int_val > 1000) THEN
  LEAVE test_loop;
END IF;

SET int_val = int_val +1;
insert into empmast (name) values ( 'Client ' + int_val );
END LOOP; 
END;
```

Does this mean that MySQL is way slower in data insertion?

Comment: Why are you creating a stored procedure in one case and have just a loop in the other. Wouldn't having basically the same code give you a more fair result?

Comment: @jonny Mysql only allows loops in stored procedures (and functions)

Comment: @P.Salmon The reason for mySql taking much longer could be related to the fact that a stored procedure is compiled too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no - I suspect it's more to do with when and how often the insert is committed. For example in the following (fixed) version of your query I have set autocommit to 0 (off) before entering the loop and committed after the loop terminates. On my pc this brings the execution time down from 34 secs to 0.25 sec

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS xproc_loop_test;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE xproc_loop_test()
BEGIN

  DECLARE int_val INT DEFAULT 0;
    set autocommit = 0;
  test_loop : LOOP
  IF (int_val > 998) THEN
        LEAVE test_loop;
    END IF;

    SET int_val = int_val +1;
    insert into empmast (name) values (concat( 'Client ' , int_val) );

END LOOP;
commit; 
END $$;
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks Salmon,Go it. Committing after all the insertions truly is making a phenomenal performance change. But remember, in SQL server I did not need to set the commit for the end.

Comment: SQL server does it for you -its one of the behavioral differences between mysql and sql server.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently MySQL is much slower than SQL Server for this use case. In my experience MySQL is often far faster than this. And, SQL Server is often slower.  For what it's worth my MariaDB 10.0.x instance is not slow on this, taking 32ms.

Many factors affect bulk insert performance. RDMS servers do a lot of invisible work when users insert rows, such as building BTREE indexes and maintaining transactional data integrity.

It's unwise to extrapolate from simple test cases, especially of sequential values, to draw general conclusions about performance. Sequential value insertion can sometimes require BTREE rebalancing, which can be time consuming.

In MySQL, wrapping your insertion loops in a transaction makes a big performance difference.  Like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
test_loop : LOOP
  IF (int_val > 998) THEN
    LEAVE test_loop;
  END IF;

  SET int_val = int_val +1;
  insert into empmast (name) values (concat( 'Client ' , int_val) );

END LOOP;
COMMIT;
```

Why? because you've told MySQL it can build up a batch of records to insert all in one go, and it can update your indexes in one go.

If you're using a program to insert a million rows, it's often smart to wrap them in transactions of a few thousand rows each.