# Mysql: How to get a result for each day in between an start and an end date from a table that contains also a start and an end date?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, stored-procedures

I have a start date and an end date. For each day between start and end date I like to get a result, even if there are no results within my stats table.

The best suggestion to solve this is a stored procedure what creates a temporary table for each date (day) so that I could create a join.

```
BEGIN

    declare d datetime;
    create temporary table joindates (d date not null);

    SET d = fkstartdate;

    WHILE d <= fkenddate DO

        insert into joindates (d) values (d);
        set d = date_add(d, interval 1 day);

    END WHILE;


SELECT * FROM `joindates` AS tempt LEFT JOIN `radacct` AS stats 
ON stats.acctstarttime <= tempt.d AND (stats.acctstoptime >= tempt.d OR stats.acctstoptime IS NULL) AND calledstationid = calledstationid 
ORDER BY tempt.d ASC;

    drop temporary table joindates;

END
```

The join is not finalized now (just for testing). But as you see, the join would be perfect if the "radacct" table would use just one date col. Than I could easily create a JOIN by using the = operator for ON.

Now the "radacct" however is using acctstarttime and acctstoptime for there entries (I can not modify this table, is given by the radius server) both are datetime types.

So in my query I need all entries between my start and stop date where acctstarttime has started in the past or within my time period. And acctstoptime is within my time period, after my time period or NULL (active session).

The problem with my JOIN solution: Its slow as hell
Do you may have any faster query ideas please?

Thanks

Appendix1: It is very important that I get a result for each entry on each day that matches my period of days, even if acctstarttime to acctstoptime goes over multiple days. So that I always get all users online.

Appendix2:
As requested, the full table structure of "radacct" – the accounting table of the freeradius MySql module …

```
CREATE TABLE `radacct` (
 `radacctid` bigint(21) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `acctsessionid` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `acctuniqueid` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `groupname` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `realm` varchar(64) DEFAULT '',
 `nasipaddress` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `nasportid` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
 `nasporttype` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 `acctstarttime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `acctstoptime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `acctsessiontime` int(12) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `acctauthentic` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 `connectinfo_start` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `connectinfo_stop` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `acctinputoctets` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `acctoutputoctets` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `calledstationid` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `callingstationid` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `acctterminatecause` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `servicetype` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 `framedprotocol` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 `framedipaddress` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `acctstartdelay` int(12) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `acctstopdelay` int(12) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `xascendsessionsvrkey` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`radacctid`),
 UNIQUE KEY `acctuniqueid` (`acctuniqueid`),
 KEY `username` (`username`),
 KEY `framedipaddress` (`framedipaddress`),
 KEY `acctsessionid` (`acctsessionid`),
 KEY `acctsessiontime` (`acctsessiontime`),
 KEY `acctstarttime` (`acctstarttime`),
 KEY `acctstoptime` (`acctstoptime`),
 KEY `nasipaddress` (`nasipaddress`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2041894 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: How large are the tables?  Are there overlaps?

Comment: The table will grow very large over a  long time since it stores all accounting data from hotspots connected to my radius server. Every entry is related to a clients mac address. However the mac address could have multiple entries for each session a client starts (first connected to a hotspot, connection lost from hotspot). The only unique value is a session id for each active session until it ends. So on session start  "acctstarttime" gets set and "acctstoptime" remains NULL. Session gets terminated – "acctstoptime" gets the end date". If the same client connects again a new entry is inserted

Comment: My other approach is the query in a while for each date (in between the period) one request. It would give me all online users for every day. But lets say I like to request 60 days, that would be 60 selects :P so I guess that's not better than the join?

Comment: Could be the inserts are slow have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242879/mysql-performance-vs-mssql-performance/38243522?noredirect=1#comment63939066_38243522

Comment: Is "using only mysql" a real constraint ? or do you have some other language involved (e.g : a web site running php or python or ... ) ?

Comment: Also : could you post the strutcure of your 'radacct' table ? `SHOW CREATE TABLE radacct`

Comment: Thank you so far. Here are some updates – I tried to use a TRANSACTION for the inserts (should be the same as set autocommit = 0) as recommended by P.Salmon. So that took for 60 days 0.0351 only. So the problem must be the join. @LeGEC of course I can use PHP, but in the past a mixed solution performed often slower than MySql only and I would prefer MySql over PHP. So yes of course I can provide the table structure. "raddact" is the regular accounting table of the freeradiusservers MySql modul. I'll append it to the original Question above :)

Comment: Well I finally came to the conclusion that there might be a MySql solution for that task but it would take to much effort to find it. I will stick to @LeGEC suggestion and handle one part in PHP so that should improve the speed as much as needed because no more temp table and join will be necessary ;) thanks anyways to all that tried to help me!